# What is a good/reliable source for current and historic gold prices?

Tags: gold, websites, price

In searching for the current and historic price of gold, the kinds of sites I'm finding seem a bit questionable.

What is a reputable site for information about current and historic prices for gold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kitco](http://www.kitco.com/charts/historicalgold.html)

[Gold prices, 1833-Present](http://www.nma.org/pdf/gold/his_gold_prices.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

[Real time gold price in euro/grams](http://www.nummus.com), but no historical prices.